# Is it possible to do Postgresql writable slave?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Is it possible to do writable slave in postgresql master-slave replication model?
Db contains just one unindexed table.

I managed to achieve it with BDR master-master replication, but it eventually tables become locked to writes, both master and slave, for some reason, so I was forced to remove it and try something else.

Im looking to Slony and burcado now, but not sure from docs that I can get writable slave.

Comment: in case someone find this - since version 10 there is logical replication in postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since version 10 there is logical replication in postgresql, so I used it

*added this answer just to stop SO bugging me of unaccepted answer. Adina's answer unfortunately can't be it at all.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a writable replica using Slony; I'm doing that now at work.

However: the tables that are being replicated can't be modified. You can have other tables in the same database and schema that are writable, just not the ones being replicated.